# Make a Web Page Appear Fully Loaded, or jQuery to MooTools Translation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, mootools

I want a web page to appear in the browser only after it finished loading all its elements.

My usual solution is to delay showing the page until after all the elements finished loading. I use this in CSS:

```
body {
opacity: 0;
}
```

– and place this jQuery snippet in the `<head>` of the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
        $('body').animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
}); 
</script>
```

– to smoothly fade in the complete page.

However, the page I'm working on has MooTools library linked to it. I do not want to make the page even heavier by linking jQuery to it, as well, but I'm unfamiliar with MooTools, and could use a bit of help.

**Question:** what's the exact MooTools translation of the jQuery snippet I typed above?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive you are looking for this:

```
window.addEvent('load', function() {
  $$('body').set('morph', {duration: 300}).morph({'opacity': '1'});
});
```

source [**here**](http://demos111.mootools.net/DomReadyVS.Load)

morph instead of animate in mootools source [**here**](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Fx/Fx.Morph)

#### Further Info

So `$('block')` is like saying `getElementById('block')` gets `<div id="block"></div>`

`$$('body')` is like `getElementsByTagName(body)` gets `<body></body>`

`$$('.block')` will also get `<div class="block"></div>`

great source [**here**](http://solutoire.com/2007/09/20/understanding-mootools-selectors-e-and-es/)

Comment: Thank you, David! But what should I put between { }? Or should it be exactly the code suggested by Explosion Pills?

Comment: – hey David, something isn't working. I set body opacity to 0 in CSS, and placed the code you suggested in the head section of the page, between <script> tags. However, the page fails to fade in, I only see the background, but not the main divs. I suspect I'm doing something wrong. Could you please help?

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov  try it out now, needed `$$` to get element by tag name

Comment: hmm... interesting. The main body of the page seems to load as a single entity, but the background appears first, and then the rest of the stuff about half a second later. Also - how can I make the fade-in slower? It seems to just pop up, in all browsers...

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov  Maybe open a new question and post your code? instead of cluttering the comments or continue this conversation in the chat room??

Comment: – Chatroom would be a good idea, but how can I get in touch with you via chatroom? (I don't think I ever used it before, no idea where the button is, even! Help, please?)

Comment: How do I talk in that thing, @David Chase? There seems to be no text area or submit button?

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov should be able to talk lower left bottom of screen textarea and send button try this http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/27770/mootools-from-jquery and click `join room`

Comment: – the inscription at the bottom of the page says I have to be logged in to be able to talk. I AM logged in, but nothing's happening. I guess I'd have to post a separate question.

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov try logging in again, maybe it will realize that you are logged in

Comment: – tried a few times, no luck. Posting a separate question, would appreciate your taking a look.

Comment: here's the new question – thank you very much! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884441/smoothly-fade-in-entire-web-page-with-mootools

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {
    $("gallery").set('morph', {duration: 3000})
    .morph({opacity: 1});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/9tqxr/

`'load'` will probably work too, but from what I can see `domready` seems to be preferred.

Comment: i believe the OP was looking for exact `load` equivalent in mootoos which is done below.... `domready` is the same as `ready` in jQuery

Comment: you answer uses `domready` which is not the equivalent to `load` therefore it doesnt make sense why you posted `domready`

Comment: Thank you, @Explosion Pills - that's what I was looking for! Your response also revealed to me a minor mistake I made in quoting my jQuery snippet: by "#gallery" I actually meant "body". I updated it in my snippet in the body of the question, just in case anyone reads it in the future and gets confused.